# Why does a Java method reference with return type match the Consumer interface?

Tags: java, java-8

I am confused by the following code

```
class LambdaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Consumer<String>         lambda1 = s -> {};
        Function<String, String> lambda2 = s -> s;

        Consumer<String>         lambda3 = LambdaTest::consume; // but s -> s doesn't work!
        Function<String, String> lambda4 = LambdaTest::consume;
    }

    static String consume(String s) { return s;}
}
```

I would have expected the assignment of lambda3 to fail as my consume method does not match the accept method in the Consumer Interface - the return types are different, String vs. void.

Moreover, I always thought that there is a one-to-one relationship between Lambda expressions and method references but this is clearly not the case as my example shows.

Could somebody explain to me what is happening here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`consume(String)` method matches `Consumer<String>` interface, because it consumes a `String` - the fact that it returns a value is irrelevant, as - in this case - it is simply ignored. (Because the `Consumer` interface does not expect any return value at all).

It must have been a design choice and basically a utility: imagine how many methods would have to be refactored or duplicated to match needs of functional interfaces like `Consumer` or even the very common `Runnable`. (Note that you can pass any method that consumes no parameters as a `Runnable` to an `Executor`, for example.)

Even methods like `java.util.List#add(Object)` return a value: `boolean`. Being unable to pass such method references just because that they return *something* (that is mostly irrelevant in many cases) would be rather annoying.

Comment: Well, this effectively means that any Function can always be used as a Consumer, right? I wasn't aware of this design choice, so thanks for pointing this out. Still, why then are Function Lambdas like s -> s not allowed as Consumer arguments?

Comment: Well, there's always the Java typing issue, so you can't pass a constructed `Function` as `Consumer` or cast/assign it to a `Consumer` variable. It still uses the same old Java typing mechanism - you can think of lambdas as anonymous classes, except with prettier syntax and different internals. (I won't go into details, but chances are that they do not compile into the same exact bytecode.) *However*, any method that could construct a `Function<A, B>` (that consumes type `A`), could be used to construct a `Consumer<A>`.

Comment: About the `s -> s` - my guess is that if you explicitly define a new lambda without referencing an existing method, you *have* to follow its exact method signature. In this case, `Consumer<String>` does not return anything, so you cannot just end the lambda with a line that basically stands for `return s;`. `s -> s.toString()` (which would pretty have the same result) should work, as the method would be simply invoked and its result (`s`) would be ignored.

Comment: It does work indeed! Amazing! `s -> s` triggers a compiler error "Void methods cannot return a value" but `s -> s.toString()` is accepted. I still don't understand the difference between these two Lambda expressions.

Comment: `s -> s` is an equivalent of `s -> { return s; }`, which fails to compile, as `Consumer` method cannot return a value. `s -> s.toString()` might seem to "do" the same thing, but it actually is an equivalent of `s -> { s.toString(); }`, which simply invokes a method, but does not return anything. So - in the first example, you're trying to *return* a value. In the second, you're actually invoking a method and ignoring its result.

Comment: I think I understand it now :-) If the target type is a `Consumer`, then `s -> s.toString()`is interpreted as `s -> { s.toString(); }`. If the target type is a `Function`, then the same lambda is interpreted as `s -> { return s.toString(); }`

Comment: Yes, that's it. Is there anything you'd like me to add to the original answer or can it be accepted as it is?

Comment: Your original answer is certainly acceptable in light of our discussion. Thanks again for your patience in explaining these things. Type inference does sometimes lead to suprising conclusions!

Comment: Here's the basis for this design decision: Java allows you to *call* a method and ignore the return value (a method invocation expression as a statement).  Since we allow this at the invocation, we also allow this when adapting a method to a functional interface whose arguments are compatible but the functional interface is void-returning.

Comment: Note also that we'll do other adaptations (boxing, unboxing) to make the shape of the lambda match up with the expected shape of the functional interface.  Ignoring a return value is just one of those adaptations.

Comment: A convenient way to adapt a `Function<T,R>` to a `Consumer<T,R>` is to append `::apply` to a Function instance; then the Function return type can be ignored like any other method that returns a value, e.g. `Function<String,Integer> f = String::length; Consumer<String> c = f::apply;`

Answer (score 27):

As [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) pointed out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308294/why-does-a-java-method-reference-with-return-type-match-the-consumer-interface#comment62144050_37308580), the basis for the design decision was to allow adapting a method to a functional interface the same way you can call the method, i.e. you can call every value returning method and ignore the returned value.

When it comes to lambda expressions, things get a bit more complicated. There are two forms of lambda expressions, `(args) -> expression` and `(args) -> { statements* }`.

Whether the second form is `void` compatible, depends on the question whether no code path attempts to return a value, e.g. `() -> { return ""; }` is not `void` compatible, but expression compatible, whereas `() -> {}` or `() -> { return; }` are `void` compatible. Note that `() -> { for(;;); }` and `() -> { throw new RuntimeException(); }` are both, `void` compatible and value compatible, as they don’t complete normally and there’s no `return` statement.

The form `(arg) -> expression` is value compatible if the expression evaluates to a value. But there are also expressions, which are *statements* at the same time. These expressions may have a side effect and therefore can be written as stand-alone statement for producing the side effect only, ignoring the produced result. Similarly, the form `(arg) -> expression` can be `void` compatible, if the expression is also a statement.

An expression of the form `s -> s` can’t be `void` compatible as `s` is not a statement, i.e. you can’t write `s -> { s; }` either. On the other hand `s -> s.toString()` can be `void` compatible, because method invocations are statements. Similarly, `s -> i++` can be `void` compatible as increments can be used as a statement, so `s -> { i++; }` is valid too. Of course, `i` has to be a field for this to work, not a local variable.

The Java Language Specification [§14.8. Expression Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) lists all expressions which may be used as statements. Besides the already mentioned method invocations and increment/ decrement operators, it names assignments and class instance creation expressions, so `s -> foo=s` and `s -> new WhatEver(s)` are `void` compatible too.

As a side note, the form `(arg) -> methodReturningVoid(arg)` is the *only* expression form that is not value compatible.

Comment: Thanks for this enlightening discussion of the design rationales especially with regard to the notions of `void` and value compatibility. I wasn't aware that `void` plays such a special role in type compatibility questions.    I first stumbled onto this when I saw somewhere `StringBuilder::append` being used both as a `BiFunction` and a `BiConsumer` in `Stream.reduce()` and `Stream.collect()`, respectively. I understand now why this is possible but I am still wondering whether this constitutes fair use or abuse ...

Comment: As said, you can always call a method for its side-effect and ignore the returned result and so you can do with a method reference/lambda expression. That’s a fair use. It would be bad code if you invoke a method that way that is known to have no side effect, e.g. `s -> s.toString()` is suspicious. Similarly, an expression of the form `i -> i++` which modifies the *parameter*, which has no persisting effect, is strongly discouraged.

Comment: "complete normally" is used incorrectly here. According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1, a return statement is abrupt completion, not normal completion.

Comment: "value-compatible" is defined in [(§15.27.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) as "A block lambda body is value-compatible if it cannot complete normally (§14.21) and every return statement in the block has the form return Expression;."

Comment: The statement in the answer "whether all code paths that complete normally won’t attempt to return a value" implies that returning a value is considered completing normally. This should be corrected.

Comment: @Kylos you are right; I somehow missed the edit comment