# java streams - How to filter a collection to two new collections

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I tried to create two lists - odds and evens as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21));
    List<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.stream().forEach(x -> x % 2 == 0 ? evens.add(x) : odds.add(x));
}
```

But it gave me incompatible types error (bad return type in lambda expression
    missing return value)

What is the best way to filter a collection to two new collections?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can make your existing code compile with a trivial modification:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {         
     List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21));
     List<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<>();
     List<Integer> evens = new ArrayList<>();
     numbers.stream().forEach(x -> (x % 2 == 0 ? evens : odds).add(x));
 }
```

The conditional `?:` operator is an *expression*, which isn't a valid statement on its own. My modified code changes the use of the conditional operator to just select which list to add to, and then calls `add` on it - and that method invocation expression *is* a valid statement.

An alternative would be to `collect` using `Collectors.partitioningBy` - although in this particular case that would probably be more confusing code than what you've got.

Comment: calling `forEach` on a Stream does not guarantee the correct ordering, you have to use `forEachOrdered` instead. On the other hand, in this case you don’t need a stream at all, so you can just invoke `forEach` on the original `List` to get the right result. Though using a Stream and `partitioningBy` is much cleaner…

Comment: As a side note, `List.add` is not declared `void`, it returns a `boolean` (always `true`), so you *can* use it in a ternary expression. But the ternary expression itself is not a statement and hence, inappropriate as `Consumer`. In your changed variant, the resulting expression still returns a `boolean`, but a method invocation is a statement and can be invoked while ignoring the result, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37308294/2711488)

Answer (score 9):

As the other answers explain why it doesn't compile I would use in your case the `partitioningBy` collector and fetch the resulting lists:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.partitioningBy;

...

List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 13, 21);

Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> partition = 
    numbers.stream().collect(partitioningBy(x -> x % 2 == 0));

List<Integer> odds = partition.get(false);
List<Integer> evens = partition.get(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

A ternary operator is not a statement. If you're using a `forEach` block, you'd need a valid Java statement, or a complete block:

```
numbers.stream().forEach(x -> {
    if (x % 2 == 0 ) { 
        pairs.add(x); 
    } else { 
        ods.add(x);
    }
});
```