# CompletableFutures strange behavior with callbacks

Tags: java, completable-future

I want to experiment with abilities of CompletableFutures, to do this i create simple class `CompletableFutureTests`

this is my methods:

```
private static String name() {
    System.out.println("Name");
    return "ALmas";
}

@SneakyThrows(InterruptedException.class)
private static String surname(String name) {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("sur");
    return name+" Abdrazak";
}

private static String world(String name) {
    System.out.println("world");
    return name + " hello";
}

private void consumer(String str){
    System.out.println("str");
}

private static String onExc(Exception name) {
    return "on exception";
}
```

And usage

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CompletableFutureTests::name)
                         .thenApplyAsync(CompletableFutureTests::surname)
                         .thenApply(CompletableFutureTests::world)
                         .thenAccept(CompletableFutureTests::consumer);
```

This code throw me

```
RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept
```

due to this line

```
.thenAccept(CompletableFutureTests::consumer)
```

When i replace it with new class

```
private static class Test implements Consumer<String>{

        @Override
        public void accept(String t) {
           System.out.println(t);
        }
        }

    }

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CompletableFutureTests::name)
                             .thenApplyAsync(CompletableFutureTests::surname)
                             .thenApply(CompletableFutureTests::world)
                             .thenAccept(new Test());
```

It works as aspected. As you can see method reference to method `consumer` and method `apply` from `Test` class are identical

Why first one doesn't work?

BTW

Why this one is also correct

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(CompletableFutureTests::name)
                             .thenApplyAsync(CompletableFutureTests::surname)
                             .thenApply(CompletableFutureTests::world)
                             .thenAccept(CompletableFutureTests::surname);
```

(I pass method reference to method surname to `thenAccept` but `thenAccept` should take `Consumer` as arg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why first one doesn't work?

It doesn't work because your **consumer()** method is not static; you are providing an instance method where a static method is required. Make it a static method and your code will work:

```
private static void consumer(String str) {
    System.out.println("str");
}
```

> BTW Why this one is also correct

(i.e. Why can you successfully provide a method reference that returns a value when the required argument is a Consumer with no return value?)

Your question is a duplicate of this SO question: [Why does a Java method reference with return type match the Consumer interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308294/why-does-a-java-method-reference-with-return-type-match-the-consumer-interface)

In particular note these comments from [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz):

*Here's the basis for this design decision: Java allows you to call a method and ignore the return value (a method invocation expression as a statement). Since we allow this at the invocation, we also allow this when adapting a method to a functional interface whose arguments are compatible but the functional interface is void-returning.*

*Note also that we'll do other adaptations (boxing, unboxing) to make the shape of the lambda match up with the expected shape of the functional interface. Ignoring a return value is just one of those adaptations.*

Also see [this answer from Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308294/why-does-a-java-method-reference-with-return-type-match-the-consumer-interface/37318579?s=1%7C82.0169#37318579):

*...the basis for the design decision was to allow adapting a method to a functional interface the same way you can call the method, i.e. you can call every value returning method and ignore the returned value.*