# OCPJP 8 II Consumer vs Supplier IZ0-809

Tags: java-8

I am trying to get IZO-809 certification I was reading the OCA/OCP SE8 test book and a code really caught my attention.

The code gets me to this question.

I know consumer get a parameter and not return nothing and Supplier has not parameters and returns a value.

But this code is almost the same after the ->.

```
public class Pregunta24{
   private final Object obj;
   public Pregunta24(final Object obj){
      this.obj = obj;
   }    
}
//Returns a Supplier
private final Supplier<Pregunta24>supplier = ()->new Pregunta24("HI");
//Returns a Consumer.
private final Consumer<Pregunta24>consumer = a->new Pregunta24(a);
```

Both codes work.

But if this code not work i know that consumer doesn't return nothing.

```
private final Consumer<String>consumerString = String::length
```

I know this not work because consumer doesn't return a value my question is in the supplier code and the consumer code the code is right after the -> mark but this time is considered return in fact a instance of the class.

My question is why sometimes Java complaints that is a return value and something not?

I mean this code.

```
private final Supplier<Pregunta24>supplier = ()->new Pregunta24("HI");
// I would think is returning a instance of the Pregunta24 class.
private final Consumer<Pregunts24>consumer = a->new Pregunta24(a);
```

Is returning the same after the -> but why in the consumer don't say the error.

```
incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
```

But if do this I do

```
final Consumer<String>consumerString = a->1;
```

I think the code after the -> is context inferred.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41483237/2711488

Comment: See also [Why does a Java method reference with return type match the Consumer interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37308294/2711488)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to javadoc [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html):

> Represents an operation that accepts a single input argument and
>   returns no result.

```
Consumer<Pregunts24>consumer = a->new Pregunta24(a);
```

doesn't actually return anything. This basically is implementation of [`Consumer#accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-) method, which accepts an object of type `T` and has `void` as return type.

```
public void accept(Pregunta24 a) {
    new Pregunta24(a);
}
```

You are not returning anything. Same thing with

```
Consumer<String>consumerString = String::length
public void accept(String a) {
    a.length();
}
```

However

```
Consumer<String>consumerString = a->1;
```

is an invalid expression which is translated to something like this:

```
 public void accept(String a) {
        1;
 }
```

Comment: But why the implementation of the consumerSring a->1 is a compiler error if in the accept is not returning nothing neither?

Comment: @chiperortiz, because java language specification doesn't recognize `1;` as a valid expression. Please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8. Try to declare `public class Main { public static void main(String[] args) { 1; } }` and you will see the same error, it is not about `Consumer`, but Java lang spec instead.