# Java assignment operator returns value in lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, operators

In java, if we write

```
int a = 3;
int b = (a = 100);
System.out.println(b) // 100
```

then `b` will actually have data of 100 because assignment operator `=` returns a value.

A strange thing happens when I combine it with lambda expression:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Function<Integer, Integer> func = i -> i = 1;   // COMPILES
    Consumer<Integer> con = i -> i = 1;             // ALSO COMPILES
    Consumer<Integer> con2 = i -> 1                 // DOES NOT COMPILE

    System.out.println(func.apply(34));             // 1
    con.accept(12);
}
```

In the first lambda expression, the `Function` accepts a value and returns a value, which makes sense.

A consumer, however, shouldn't return any value. In this case, it does and the code still compiles…

Can somebody explain that to me please? Thank you.

Comment: consumer will ignore the return type

Answer (score 2):

`i=1` is an expression that is also a statement. It has an `int` value.

Since it is a statement, it can serve as the body of a lambda expression that implements a functional interface whose method has a `void` return type.

Just like you are allowed to write:

```
public void accept (int i) 
{
    i = 1;
}
```

On the other hand, `1` is an expression which is not a statement. Therefore it cannot be used as a body of a lambda expression that implements a functional interface whose method has a `void` return type.

Just like you cannot write:

```
public void accept (int i) 
{
    1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but that hasn't answered my question. First of all, in your first method, in order to match my lambda, should it be return (i=1);? And the second method is a syntax error, so of course we cannot write it that way. So my question is why i -> i=1 works for Consumer AND Function?

Comment: @AnhMinhTran My two sample methods are explaining why `Consumer<Integer> con = i -> i = 1; ` passes compilation while `Consumer<Integer> con2 = i -> 1 ` does not.

Comment: I just read the explanation in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308294/why-does-a-java-method-reference-with-return-type-match-the-consumer-interface and it makes sense to me. Is it just something that Java developers did for convenience? As long as the function match the parameter, if it returns something redundant, just ignores it?

Comment: @AnhMinhTran I'm not sure which answer you are referring to. The second (unaccepted) answer is the correct answer in my opinion (`the basis for the design decision was to allow adapting a method to a functional interface the same way you can call the method, i.e. you can call every value returning method and ignore the returned value.`).