# why BiConsumer Funcational Interface accepts methods having return type

Tags: java, java-8

I understood BiConsumer has a method which accepts 2 agrs and returns void.

In this case, how map.put is accepted which in takes 2 args and returns value??

```
Map<String,String> roles = new HashMap<>();
BiConsumer<String, String> consumer= (s,t) -> roles.put(s,t);
consumer.accept("XX", "XXXXX");
```

i expected below line to fail

```
BiConsumer<String, String> consumer(s,t) -> roles.put(s,t);
```

same way i expected below one to fail as it needs string instance and string literal to add/concat and returns string

```
BiConsumer<String, String> concat = String::concat; or
concat = (s,t) -> s.concat(t);
```

it seems like i've misunderstood something but not able to understand.
can someone explain why my understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BiConsumer<String, String> consumer= (s,t) -> {
   String result = roles.put(s,t); // result is ignored
   return;
}
```

Also called special void compatibility rule in the `JLS`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i just figured it out. Thanks for your time, will accept it as answer

Comment: @WhyJava [§15.27.2 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) for reference. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482574/lambda-special-void-compatibility-rule-statement-expression) and all its linked questions.

Comment: And [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308294/why-does-a-java-method-reference-with-return-type-match-the-consumer-interface#comment62144050_37308580) from the one who must know it…

Comment: @Eugene, can you change the variable name of string, as it will cause compilation error. i dont want someone else point it out or misunderstand the concept