# AssertThrows in JUNIT5

Tags: java, junit, java-8

I am trying to learn `assertThrows` in `junit5`, it takes `Executable` as 2nd arg which has a `void execute()` method. But while going through the example on the same in the below example we are passing it a `LAMBDA` which returns a double with method `double divide(int a , int b)`. Now how is it possible to pass the below lambda if it does not have the same signature as the `execute` method of the `Excecutable`. It should give `compile error` right?

```
assertThrows(ArithmeticException.class,() -> m.divide(1, 0),"Failed");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
() -> m.divide(1, 0)
```

is treated effectively like

```
new Executable() {
  @Override public void execute() {
    m.divide(1, 0);
  }
}
```

The lambda can be treated like an instance of any interface/class with a single abstract method.

Lambdas are always polyexpressions, meaning that their exact type is determined by the context in which they are used.

There is no compatibility issue.

Comment: But divide will return a double whereas execute is void. Will the result be absorbed? I am confused :(

Comment: @ghostrider: That a method returns a value does not imply that you have to do something with it. In this case the compiler correctly resolves the expression and discards the returned value.

Comment: Then why do we get compilation error when we return something from a void method in a simple void method?

Comment: @ghostrider: Because thats invalid syntax (you manually defined), whereas in this case the compiler automatically knows the correct syntax to use.

Comment: @ghostrider the return value will simply be ignored. It's a *void-compatible* lambda.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41483237/2711488) and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37318579/2711488)