# Why does method reference can be used instead of PropertyChangeListener?

Tags: java, javabeans, method-reference, propertychangelistener

In the following Java code, [`PropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.desktop/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) is implemented in two ways: 1) using a class that implements `PropertyChangeListener` interface, and 2) using a method reference.

According to the API, the `addPropertyChangeListener` method takes, as argument, an object of type `PropertyChangeListener`. The first approach (Commented line in main method in PointTest class) is implemented in this way.

But in the second approach, just a method reference is passed to the `addPropertyChangeListener` method (i.e. `handlePropertyChange`). Surprisingly, the method is void! So, my questions are "How does the second approach work? and why does the code compile in the first place?!"

```
class Point {
    private int x, y;
    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        int oldX = this.x;
        this.x = x;
        pcs.firePropertyChange("x", oldX, x);
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    }
}

class PointTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p = new Point(1, 2);
//        p.addPropertyChangeListener(new myPropertyChangeListener());      // <--- first approach
        p.addPropertyChangeListener(PointTest::handlePropertyChange);       // <--- second approach

        p.setX(10);
        p.setX(20);

    }

    public static void handlePropertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        String propertyName = e.getPropertyName();

        if("x".equals(propertyName)) {
            System.out.println("x has changed:");
            System.out.println("\t old: " + e.getOldValue());
            System.out.println("\t new: " + e.getNewValue());
        }

    }
}

class myPropertyChangeListener implements PropertyChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        String propertyName = e.getPropertyName();

        if("x".equals(propertyName)) {
            System.out.println("x has changed:");
            System.out.println("\t old: " + e.getOldValue());
            System.out.println("\t new: " + e.getNewValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308294/why-does-a-java-method-reference-with-return-type-match-the-consumer-interface or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8

Comment: Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html.